# Extracting rows with a consecutive pattern that exceeds a threshold

Tags: mysql, window-functions, correlated-subquery

I currently have this set of data.

| Id | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 |

I have ids sorted ascending, and a column called pattern. The goal is to retrieve only the rows with a consecutive pattern >=3 down the table.

So the result would be:

| Id | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 |

Since the pattern for Ids 3-6 have consecutively reached >=3, we will return these 4 rows.
Same goes for Ids 9-11.

Id 1-2 did not reach the threshold of 3. Same for Id 7-8.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this have to be done in MySQL?  It sounds like it would be easier in your code/application to do this rather than the database.

Comment: Yeap. Only looking for mysql solutions for now. I agree its probably easier if I use python or smth, but this was a database question I was given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM()` window function to create the groups of the sequences and with `MAX()` window function check the max pattern in each group:

```
SELECT Id, pattern
FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(pattern) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) max_pattern
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(pattern = 1) OVER (ORDER BY Id) grp
    FROM tablename
  ) t
) t
WHERE max_pattern >= 3;
```

Or, with a correlated subquery, for versions of MySql that do not support window functions:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE (SELECT t2.pattern FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id + (3 - t1.pattern)) = 3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5534d8f5c06ffe81be5381b4d4e4702).